# Помогите доработать цикл для создания специального шифра

Tags: python, list, for, arraylist, while

Мне нужно, чтобы все повторяющиеся символы были вывидены в такой же последовательности и вместо, например, аааа выводилося а4 и так далее. Пример: aaaabbcaa = a4b2c1a2. Вышло только с первым символом, а дальше не могу понять что сделать, чтобы перебросило на следующий символ и посчитало его. ОЧЕНЬ ВАЖНО: не делать это слишком сложными методами, а использовать только циклы, списки, ну и там по мелочи

```
_string = str(input())
_sum = 0

for i in(_string[0:]): # отвечает за символ
    for j in _string[+1]: # отвечает за цифру
        if i == j: # ПОДСЧЕТ
            _sum += 1 #ПОДСЧЕТ
        else: # ПОДСЧЕТ
            _string = _string[0+1:] # переброс на след. символ

print(j + str(_sum))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно без вложенных кучи `for`:

**вариант 1:**

```
text = "aaaabbcaa"

res = text[0]
count = 1

for l in text[1:]:
    if l == res[-1]:
        count += 1
    else:
        res += str(count) + l
        count = 1
res += str(count)

print(res)
```

**вариант 2:**

больше встроенных функций

```
res = ''

while text:
    letter = text[0]
    size = len(text)
    text = text.lstrip(letter)
    res += f'{letter}{size - len(text)}'
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за решение, да еще и не одно)